# Can someone help me understand this ORDER BY error in my SQL Server Query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, sql-server-2019

Ran into an error when attempting to input the query for Total Population .vs. Vaccinations:

[image: 1]

I honestly have no idea how to remedy this error and I've tried as much as I know of SQL (I'm very new to SQL) so far to mess with the code to fix it. Any suggestions? (If further code is needed, let me know and I'll post the entire project for better understanding of where the problem could stem from)

Comment: First of all, you should copy the `SELECT` statement as text into the question. And the error message as well, of course. This will help find people willing to read your question.

Comment: Can you try `ORDER BY dea.Location, dea.DATE` instead of `ORDER BY 2,3`?

Comment: I foresee many issues in the future if you do not start with a solid schema on which to build. Why is the column Location (and perhaps Date) so large? For that matter, why do you use three part names? Your connection should determine the database to use for your object references. And don't order by ordinal position - it is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is complaining about "`ORDER BY` clause of `RANGE` window frame" - and you're probably looking at your code, not seeing `RANGE` and not knowing what it's talking about.

It helps then to know that `RANGE` is an optional part of the [`OVER` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
OVER (   
   [ <PARTITION BY clause> ]  
   [ <ORDER BY clause> ]   
   [ <ROW or RANGE clause> ]  
  )
```

This then, helps us to know that the error is specifically complaining about this part of your query:

```
OVER (PARTITION BY dea.LOCATION ORDER BY dea.LOCATION, dea.DATE)
```

So, next we read the message again and realise that it's complaining about the combined width of the data stored in the `dea.LOCATION` and `dea.DATE` columns. Without seeing the column definitions, I'd guess any `DATE` column is going to be reasonably small so it's reasonable to assume that most of the data comes from the `LOCATION` column.

On the one hand, we could try to reduce the width of this column, by taking a substring for instance. But if we look again at the whole `OVER()` clause, we'll realise that it's not needed in the `ORDER BY` part at all.

Why?

Because that same column is being used to partition the data. The `ORDER BY` defines ordering *within* each partition - but if each partition only contains rows which share the same value for `dea.LOCATION`, which they will by definition, then all rows will sort equally on that column value.

So, just remove it from that `ORDER BY` and the error will disappear.